# AndroidX vs Android.support RuntimeException

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-multidex, androidx

I have some problems after update pacages from android.support to androidx...

I have this dependiences

```
 |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3 |    |    |   
    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.3 |    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1 |    |    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0 |    |   
    |    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0
    -> 27.1.1 |    |    |    |    |         |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1 |    |    |    |    |
    |    \--- android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.0 |    |    |    |    |
    |         +--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.1.0 |    |    |    | 
    |         |         \--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.0 |    |    | 
    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0
    |    |    |    |    |         |    +---
    com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0 -> 27.1.1 |    |    |
    |    |         |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0
    -> 27.1.1 (*) |    |    |    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0 -> 27.1.1 |    |    | 
    |    |         |    +---
    com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1 |    |    |    |    |
    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*) |    |    | 
    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.1.0 ->
    27.1.1 |    |    |    |    |         |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1 |    |    |    |    |
    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*) |    |    | 
    |    |         |    \---
    com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1 (*) |    |    |    |  
    |         \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0 -> 27.1.1
    |    |    |    |    |              +---
    com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*) |    |    |    |    | 
    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1 (*) |    |    |    |    |              +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1
    (*) |    |    |    |    |              +---
    com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1 |    |    |    |    |
    +--- android.arch.lifecycle:livedata-core:1.1.0 |    |    |    |    |              |    +--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.1.0 |    | 
    |    |    |              |    +--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.0 | 
    |    |    |    |              |    \---
    android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.0 |    |    |    |    |              |
    \--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.0 |    |    |    |    |           
    \--- android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.0
```

I need remove `com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0` from firebasecode because

```
 AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Program type already present: android.support.v4.media.MediaMetadataCompat$RatingKey","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 

Error: Program type already present: android.support.v4.media.MediaMetadataCompat$RatingKey
```

I try this

```
api ("com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$rootProject.firebase") {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    exclude module: 'com.android.support'
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
```

and a lot of other variants but unsuccesfull

Thanks for any ideas
////////////////////FULL ERROR

```
    AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Program type already present: android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompatApi21$SubscriptionCallback","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/0, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/1, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/2, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/3, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/4, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/5, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/6, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/7, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/8, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/9, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/10, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/11, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/12, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/13, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/14, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/15, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/16, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/17, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/18, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/19, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/20, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/21, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/22, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/23, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/24, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/25, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/26, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/27, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/28, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/29, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/30, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/31, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/32, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/33, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/34, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/35, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/36, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/37, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/38, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/39, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/40, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/41, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/42, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/43, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/44, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/45, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/46, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/47, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/48, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/49, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/50, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/51, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/52, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/53, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/54, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/55, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/56, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/57, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/58, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/59, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/60, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/61, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/62, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/63, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/64, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/65, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/66, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/67, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/68, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/69, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/70, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/71, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/72, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/73, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/74, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/75, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/76, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/77, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/78, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/79, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/80, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/81, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/82, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/83, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/84, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/85, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/86, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/87, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/88, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/89, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/90, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/91, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/92, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/93, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/94, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/95, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/96, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/97, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/98, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/99, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/100, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/101, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/102, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/103, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/104, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/105, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/106, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/107, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/108, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/109, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/110, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/111, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/112, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/113, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/114, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/115, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/116, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/117, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/118, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/119, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/120, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/121, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/122, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/123, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/124, /home/parad0x/Dokumenty/AndroidProjects/Statistics/CitajCZ/statistikyCZE/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/125
Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
Program type already present: android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompatApi21$SubscriptionCallback
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:593)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(ForkJoinTask.java:677)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.join(ForkJoinTask.java:720)
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.forEach(ImmutableList.java:406)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransform.transform(DexMergerTransform.java:233)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:239)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:235)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:230)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor571.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:597)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

here is my gradle from module when i have firebase core

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'


android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdkVersion
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion rootProject.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$rootProject.supportXLibraryVersion"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    api ("com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$rootProject.firebase") {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
        exclude module: 'com.android.support'
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    implementation project(path: ':parser')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$rootProject.kotlin_version"
    implementation project(path: ':eventdatamanager')
    api project(path: ':utilities')
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

this is problem

[image: this is problem but i can't solve it]

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Could you be more specific ?

Comment: full error is was added

Comment: Would you add `build.gradle` dependencies to your question too? It's hard to check the dependencies like that structure. Thanks

Comment: i pasted but i have project with lot of module, ut firebase.core use only here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes):

> If a class appears more than once on the runtime classpath, you get an error similar to the following:
>   `Program type already present com.example.MyClass`
>
> This error typically occurs due to one of the following circumstances:
>
> A binary dependency includes a library that your app also includes as
>   a direct dependency. For example, your app declares a direct
>   dependency on Library A and Library B, but Library A already includes
>   Library B in its binary.

- **To resolve this issue**, remove Library B as a direct dependency. Your app has a local binary dependency and a remote binary dependency
  on the same library.
- **To resolve this issue**, remove one of the binary dependencies.

Whatever it is, it comes from `v4` libraries (Probably `com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0`):

```
> Program type already present:
> android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompatApi21$SubscriptionCallback
>java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives
```

And in the dependencies structure, there seems like some of the dependencies has old versions: v`26.1.0`.

**Solution:**

Check if you have added these two in `Gradle.properties`:

```
android.useAndroidX = true
android.enableJetifier = false
```

Also, you can try excluding the dependency which has the old libraries in it:

For example, it will probably be `android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.0` which has `com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0`.

Or if this didn't help, remove `build` directory(Which has intermediate folder) and rebuild the project and then it should work I hope.

Comment: i havent 
        android.useAndroidX = true
        android.enableJetifier = false on gradle, but i dont know how it use, what is parmeter android?

Comment: So probably adding those lines will help. In `gradle.settings` **If you're migrating to AndroidX**

Comment: you thing settings.gradle? i have here only modules which i want include.

Comment: i put your lines into gradle.properties (i have here only this two lines other is commented) but not work, gradle sync good but when i want rebuildProject... the same error

Comment: See : [Migrating to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/refactor). Use `Refactor -> Migrate to AndroidX`. Also, like I said in my answer, one of your dependencies are using `media-compat.androidx` and the other is from `support`. You can also try excluding on `com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics` or removing : `androidTestImplementation` dependency which has the duplicate thing.

Comment: this problem solve depencies, i can build app and launch, but inmediatly crash without error. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @trip08 Thanks for the explanation. That might be the Theme issues or the layout widgets declaration which you can also ask another question and send the link to me So that I can help you with that :)

Comment: yes i need switch androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout to androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout .. magic :D